# Rails: start script on server and then "leave"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake

I want to run a rake script on my application on Heroku that will take several hours. If I start it from my console on my laptop, and shut down my laptop the script will stop (and I will have to shut down my laptop before the script is finished).

How do I do to start this rake script without it being "tied" to my laptop. I.e. so that it continues to run until it breaks or is finished?

```
heroku run rake update_feeds_complete --app myapp
```

is the script to run...

Giving me advice on what commands etc to Google would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 6):

You can run commands with `run:detached` and close the terminal window and they will continue to run. So you simply need to run

`heroku run:detached rake update_feeds_complete --app myapp`

Comment: This is awesome! More info on the subject: [Running tasks in background](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#running-tasks-in-background)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at the scheduler, too. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler

Pretty handy for running rake tasks, even if one-offs.

Comment: I've been using scheduler too and it works like a charm. I definitely recommend it as it is super simple to use. The downside of using this Heroku add-on is that you'll have to confirm your account (and that involves a valid credit card number). Also, be aware that when you run one-off processes with this add-on, it counts towards your dyno-hours for the month. So they can charge you if you keep running lots of tasks.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I use resque and redis for jobs I want to run on heroku. If it's a one-time job I may not, but if it's something I'm going to do regularly then having them installed is a great convenience.

- **redis** installs through the ['Redis To Go' add-on with Heroku](https://addons.heroku.com/redistogo).
- **resque** is a [gem that's used for running background jobs](https://github.com/defunkt/resque/) of different kinds. There are lots of [plugins for resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque/wiki/plugins) for [sending email](https://github.com/zapnap/resque_mailer), for [job scheduling](https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler), etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Heroku in particular, but in the past when i have run into this case I used remote execute via SSH:

```
ssh username@your.server -f 'your command here'
```

This will open an ssh session, execute your command and then close the connection.  But your script will keep running remotely.

Comment: Heroku doesn't provide SSH access.